# Ant does not work as I expect in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am new to ANT and to use it, I simply created a new java project in Eclipse that just print the word Welcome in the screen. I ran the program using Eclipse and "Welcome" was successfully printed on the screen. This is my program

```
public class welcome {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome!!!");
    }
}
```

Then I just followed the usual way to build ANT file using Eclipse so I used Export feature and choose ANT buildfile. 
This the buildfile I have got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. --><project basedir="." default="build" name="test">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../../usr/lib/eclipse"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.7"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.7"/>
    <path id="test.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="welcome">
        <java classname="welcome" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

when I ran the program as Ant, it only gives me a message that build successful! without printing the "Welcome" word on screen!
This is the output

```
> Buildfile: /home/name/workspace/test/build.xml
> build-subprojects: init: build-project:
>      [echo] test: /home/name/workspace/test/build.xml build: BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 376 milliseconds
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using ANT ?? Ant is used to build artifacts what artifact you want to build and if you want to execute code why do you need ANT ?

Answer (score 1):

The default target of your ant file is "build" which will create a jar file of your project (which can be then executed later). If you want to run your project via ant, change the target to "welcome" (see the end of your ant file). That should execute the program as you expected.

Comment: And you could choose a better title to your post. Ant is working properly in Eclipse..

Comment: which target should I change? the last one has the name Welcome ` <target name="welcome">
        <java classname="welcome" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>`

Answer (score 0):

> Apache Ant is a Java library and command-line tool whose mission is to
>   drive processes described in build files as targets and extension
>   points dependent upon each other. The main known usage of Ant is the
>   build of Java applications

Also class names first letter should be CAPITALIZED ...

More or less this is how your ant should look like, but i still dont understand why you want to use ANT for whatever you are trying to do here.

```
<project name="Welcome" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="(packagename).(class name)"/>



<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```